# drupal + varnish change session cookie

Tags: drupal, cookies, session-cookies, varnish

when I request missing image on drupal site (with varnish) I receive error 404, but response contains "Set-Cookie" and it change session cookie to another (different from request)

request:
***"Cookie  SESS40dc7a980dfa6df7c793546f9fc27a91=affffbf839cd8b9b3ab6bf1130f29586;"***

response:
***"Set-Cookie SESS40dc7a980dfa6df7c793546f9fc27a91=a02895b3e7a52cd791646364d48eb588;"***

When I request without varnish, cookie not changed.

request:
***"Cookie  SESS40dc7a980dfa6df7c793546f9fc27a91=d42035f3250bc0c512ff5ba3f17df27f;"***
response:
***not found "Set-Cookie" in response***

Is varnish problem? For not 404 code is ok, cookies not changed

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that you're stripping all cookies on static content, such as your images, in **vcl_recv**. That means your backend is receiving a request without any SessionID at all (no cookies at all, actually). That simply causes Drupal/PHP to generate a new SessionID for that particular request.

If the SessionID is irrelevant to you for static content such as images, I would suggest stripping the backend response cookies from the **vcl_fetch**.